# scrollViewWillBeginDragging not working

Tags: ios, iphone

`scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, `scrollViewDidEndDragging`, `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`
not woking.

I have added two `UIScrollView` in a *VIEW.h* file and using the *VIEW.h* instance on my view controller. But i am not able to use scroll view delegates (i have already added `UIScrollViewDelegate` on .h file)

Plese help.

Comment: `scrollView.delegate  = self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have added `UIScrollViewDelegate` in the .h file Please check that you are setting delegate or not for both the scrollview i.e `scrollview1.delegate = self` and `scrollview2.delegate = self`.